# Not showing message effect after validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails...after makin validations and messaging ...still I'm not able to see effect..its not reflecting message...my code is

```
class Users < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :account_expired, :account_locked, :enabled, :id, :password, :password_expired, :username, :version

  validates :username,:password, :presence =>{:message => "Must be not blank"}

end
```

Comment: you mean the validation messages in the view ?

Comment: yes..validation message in view...

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correct - you need a [custom validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations) with an error message adding like following:

```
errors.add(:base,  'Must be not blank')
```

The reason you are seeing added username to your string is because rails calls

```
errors.add(:attribute, your_message)
```

under the hood

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print out the errors try:

```
model.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
  puts message
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also pass custom validation

for example

```
# in your model

validate:username_blank

def username_blank
 if self.username.blank? || self.username == ""
   errors[:base] << "Username Can't be Blank" # or whatever your message
 end
end
```